# wrong status for Reachability in appDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, reachability

I'm using Reachability class, which Apple provided and faced one strange thing.
App checks connection every time app did become active, and if it's active, update some data. 
When i turn on airplane mode and just after that relaunch the app, so *didBecomeActive* will be called, reachability returns wrong status(reachableViaWiFi). And if you repeat this one more time, correct status is returned.

Also i've noticed, that if you turn airplane mode, wait for a several seconds and then relaunch the app, reachability returns correct status.

Is there any explanation for such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You need to more strict when you check for connectivity. Add more condition while you receive reachability change notification.

Check below conditions:

```
- (void)reachabilityDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

    // Reachbility for internet
    Reachability *reachability = (Reachability *)[notification object];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (internetStatus) {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            break;
        }
    }

    // Reachbility for host
    Reachability *hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus) {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between the first and second switch statement? Both appear to be checking against `[reachability currentReachabilityStatus]`

Comment: @sooper: Thanks man :) I did miss that point there, edited answer.