# How to Detect wifi or 3G signal strength in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on video player using MPMediaplayer framework in iOS, I need to play two videos in my app.(i.e. My first video will play when user has strong Network signal).
My second video player will be played when their low network. I need to play my video in wifi or 3G etc... My First thing is how to detect my wifi speed in  my iphone mobile and 3G speed also. I need to get mobile wifi speed in MBPS. I am was trying to write some code. But it is not working for me. Thanks in advance.

```
#import "Reachability.h"

@interface NetworkViewController ()

@end

@implementation NetworkViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self getDataCounters];

    networkLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 40)];
    networkLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    networkLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    networkLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    networkLabel.text = myNewString;

    [self.view addSubview:networkLabel];
}

- (NSArray *)getDataCounters
{
    BOOL success;
    struct ifaddrs *addrs;

    const struct ifaddrs *cursor;
    const struct if_data *networkStatisc;

    int WiFiSent = 0;
    int WiFiReceived = 0;
    int WWANSent = 0;
    int WWANReceived = 0;

    NSString *name=[[NSString alloc]init];
    success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;

    if (success)
    {
         cursor = addrs;

         while (cursor != NULL)
         {
             name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",cursor->ifa_name];            
             NSLog(@"ifa_name %s == %@\n", cursor->ifa_name,name);

             // names of interfaces: en0 is WiFi ,pdp_ip0 is WWAN

             if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
             {
                 if ([name hasPrefix:@"en"])
                 {
                      networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;   
                      WiFiSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;   
                      WiFiReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                      NSLog(@"WiFiSent %d ==%d",WiFiSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                      NSLog(@"WiFiReceived %d ==%d",WiFiReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
                      NSLog(@"wifi data is  %.2f",(float)WiFiReceived/1048576);

                    myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f", (float)WiFiReceived/1048576];   
                    networkLabel.text = myNewString;
                }

                if ([name hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip"])
                {
                     networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;     
                     WWANSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                     WWANReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                     NSLog(@"WWANSent %d ==%d",WWANSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                     NSLog(@"WWANReceived %d ==%d",WWANReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
                }
            }

            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }

        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:WiFiSent], [NSNumber  numberWithInt:WiFiReceived],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANSent],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANReceived], nil];
}
```

Comment: Have a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675427/wrong-status-for-reachability-in-appdidbecomeactive/26675493#26675493

Comment: You seem to be implying that signal strength determines the connection speed. Which are you asking about? Pick one.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks for your response. i need to calculate signal strength..If wifi is having high bandwidth i need to display highband width video player.. if wifi having low band width then i need to play low bandwidth video player..so thats why i need to calculate wifi or 3g signal strength(in MBPS)

Comment: Signal strength is *not* measured in MB/sec. Signal strength has to do solely with the radio reception, and is measured in [dBm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm), or [ASU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_phone_signal#ASU). A connection's *bandwidth* is typically measured in bits (not bytes) per second, or factors of a thousand thereof (kbps, Mbps).

Comment: A connection usually has a theoretical upper limit on its bandwidth, but the number we *actually* care about is a connection's *throughput* (how much data per time can this pipe move). This is measured in bytes per second (or 1000's). The problem is, the only way to measure your throughput is to be actually moving that much data.  That is how online speed tests work; download a bunch of data and time it. Divide the two and there's your through put. Do the same for upload.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart as per my above code how to calcuate bandwidth in bits per seconds.?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: @SolidSoft i already using Reachability framework in my project...plz check my my query bro..

Comment: @Surya You can download above apple code and apply changes, if you are going on wrong path. It's standard code which solve your query..

Comment: @JonathonReinhart How can we measure the signal strength of WiFi network in dBm? Shall we use `CaptiveNetwork` or `NEHotspotConfiguration`? Where can I find a sample code snipped in Objective-C?

Comment: @santobedi Comments are not for questions. Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart When I ask a new question regarding it, people label it as a duplicate. I know that many people have asked such questions, however, no question has a valid answer. Anyways, I learned that I need to use `NEHotspotHelper` for my requirement. I'm still searching for ways to use it with Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

You can play high resolution video for wifi and low resolution video on cellular data.

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi    Play high resolution video
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G    Play low resolution video
}
```

Apple can reject your app if you will stream high resolution video over 3g Network.

Comment: thanks for your response.. But i need to get device bandwith..so plz guide me how can i do this thing? based on device band width i need to play video player. if i got high band width then need to play high band width video player.if i got low bandwidth then i need to play low bandwidth

Comment: There is no such kind of API or library provided by Apple. You have make webservice call for getting to know bandwidth of internet connection of your device.

Comment: webservices??based on webservices is it possible to get mobile wifi bandwidth??

Comment: Yes that is something how do you test your internet speed on your computer. Check this link http://testmy.net/results
or you can simply download a low size data and find out what is the download rate and on the basis of that you can do your own work.